# Anything special with the number 20?

Tags: counters, numbers

When counting, the number 20 is always quite different than other numbers. For example, you have 二十日 (はつか) and 二十歳 (はたち). Where does this difference come from? Is the number 20 special in Japan?

Comment: Yeah it's kind of answered in the second answer, we can close this as duplicate I guess.